# Magento 2 - Address format

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, address, format

How can I edit the address format? I know that I can add 3 more lines at **Stores/Customers/Customers** **Configuration/Name** and **Address Options/Number** of Lines in a Street Address. Then I can set as 4.

But I would like to split it in other fields like: **street, number, neighborhood, reference, etc**.

I can't find tutorials for Magento 2.x.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module on GitHub solves the problem!
https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-Address-Lines

I installed using composer and worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that from configuration. You have to customize the templates where the address fields are shown and depending on the number, you change the field's label.